# Method "exampleMethod" is never used

Tags: java, android, methods, android-studio

I am writing a Rock Paper Scissors program in android studio, here's what I have so far: (everything necessary is imported)

```
    Random compans = new Random();
    int low = 1;
    int high = 3;

    int RPS = compans.nextInt(high-low) + low;

public void rock (View view) {
    Button Rock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rock);
    Rock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /* all capitals = user answer */
            if (RPS == 1) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tie.class));
                //ROCK-rock tie
                }
            else if (RPS == 2) {
                //ROCK-paper lose
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Lose.class));
            }
            else if (RPS == 3) {
                //ROCK-scissors win
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Win.class));
            }
            }
        });
        }
public void paper (View view) {
    Button paper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paper);
    paper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (RPS == 1) {
                //PAPER-rock win
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Win.class));
            } else if (RPS == 2) {
                //PAPER-paper tie
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tie.class));
            } else if (RPS == 3) {
                //PAPER-scissors lose
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Lose.class));
            }
        }
    });
}
public void scissors (View v) {
    Button scissors = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scissors);
    scissors.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (RPS == 1) {
                    //SCISSORS-rock lose
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lose.class));
                } else if (RPS == 2) {
                    //SCISSORS-paper win
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Win.class));
                } else if (RPS == 3) {
                    //SCISSORS-scissors tie
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tie.class));
                }
            }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

When I finished, I noticed none of the "rock" "paper" or "scissor" methods were used. When I ran it on my phone, my buttons didn't do anything, same goes for the emulator.

[The message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lruw2.png)(Don't have enough rep to upload)

An explanation and solution of the message would be nice, as I'm still a beginner at this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: where do you call these methods

Comment: you did not post all of your code... also, if you are using `onClick` in XML, you should post your XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message means: you did not call any of those method when running program.

Naive solution: Move all content of 3 methods: rock,... to `onCreate()`:

```
onCreate(...){
   ...
   setContentView(...);
   //----Example for rock button
   Button Rock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rock);
   Rock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /* all capitals = user answer */
        if (RPS == 1) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tie.class));
            //ROCK-rock tie
            }
        else if (RPS == 2) {
            //ROCK-paper lose
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Lose.class));
        }
        else if (RPS == 3) {
            //ROCK-scissors win
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Win.class));
        }
        }
    });
    }

//Do the same for other buttons here

}//end of onCreate
```

Answer (score 0):

IDE is telling you that those methods were not being called. 
You didnt post the onCreate contents, you would want to move the button.setOnClick.. over in the onCreate.

On a side note instead of hooking up onclick like that you could do it on your layout file. For example

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/rock"
   android:onclick="rock"
   android:text="Rock" />
```

Here when rock button is clicked it calls "rock" button in your activity.